# Finding clusters in matrices

Tags: image-processing, matrix, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to learn about patterns in matrices. I think clustering is appropriate for such task, but not sure which clustering techniques (k-mean, hierachy, dbscan etc) are effective. Here are some examples.

1. This matrix results in 3 clusters: the diagonal line
   containing 1s, the (upper right) triangle above the diagonal line
   containing 0's, and the (lower left) triangle that contains random
   0,1's.

   ```
   1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
   0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
   1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0
   1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0
   0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0
   1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0
   1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1
   ```

When using k=3-means, I got the following result (0,1,2 indicates the label or cluster). Clearly, not what I am looking for

```
    0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2
    0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2
    0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2
    0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2
    0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 2
    0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
    0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
    1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

2. This one results in 4 clusters: the upper left 1,  the upper right 3x3 matrix of 1's , the lower left matrix of 1's, and the rest.

   ```
   1,0,0,0,1,1,1
   0,0,0,0,1,1,1
   0,0,0,0,1,1,1
   0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   1,1,1,0,0,0,0
   1,1,1,0,0,0,0
   1,1,1,0,0,0,0
   ```

k=4-mean gives the following result, which is also not what I want

```
    1 1 1 0 0 0 0
    1 1 1 0 0 0 0
    1 1 1 0 0 0 0
    2 2 1 3 3 3 3
    2 2 2 3 3 3 3
    2 2 2 3 3 3 3
    2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cluster analysis is not the tool that you are looking for.

Your requirements may be more of image processing nature than clustering.

Clustering doesn't operate "visually" on matrixes. One cell is pretty much like another in clustering, and one mostly uses matrixes because there are fast implementations available, and you end up with a short notion and reasonably high performance at the same time.
The type of matrixes used by Clustering are usually *distance matrixes*.

Furthermore, most clustering algorithms will assume attributes to be *continuous*.

If you simply map your cell to `(x,y,value)` I'm not at all surprised it does not work. The numerical ranges of the three colums do not match, and a "point" with value 0 just isn't the same as one with value 1. It's just not the data model appropriate for such algorithms.

The thing is, none of the 100 clustering algorithms I've used does what you want.

Instead, image analysis techniques will be more likely to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out techniques from image processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to agree with Anony-Mousse. No clustering technique I'm aware of could handle all your cases.

In particular, I would recommend checking out the Wikipedia page on [Image Segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation). It mentions a generalization of the kind of approach that Anony-Mousse disapproves of. For example, if you used the (x,y,value) representation such that value was weighted significantly more than the location, then *maybe* it could discover the four segments you want in your second case. That said, I wasn't able to make that work using the scipy kmeans function.